# Magnetic Mortise Latch for American Style Doors

Tags: doors, latches

I am looking to make the door handles for my kids' rooms quieter. Today I went through and oiled everything, but the latch / mortise assembly (??correct term?) that I have in my doors are still pretty noisy. I went in search or something that would be quieter.

Early in my search I found this [Tubular Mortise Silent Magnetic Internal Door Latch](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Tubular-Mortise-Silent-Magnetic-Internal-Door-Latch-63-mm-Passage-7-colors-/173346889954), but it didn't look like the kind of latch I have on my doors. So I tried searching, and everything seems to be for Europe and nothing looks like an American style latch/bolt.

Whenever I searched specifically for American or US style, all I got was electromagnetic security doors (card reader type releases) or things for cabinets.

Do they not make these in American style doors or am I just not using the right search terms? While it seems the point is to remove the strike plate, I would like to keep it since its notched into my door frame already. I would like the bolt to just be hidden away and then magnetic engage when the door is closed, mechanically pull away when the handle is pushed down.

The hope is that this would allow quieter exits from kids rooms at night. I don't need a specific brand/product recommendation, just the right terms to find this if they make them as replacements for typical USA style latches. I have a door handle similar to [this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Design-House-Stratford-Oil-Rubbed-Bronze-Passage-Hall-Closet-Door-Lever-with-Universal-6-Way-Latch-727990/206268227) if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this as it was something that I had not heard of before.
I did find a US site that sold such handles but their latch mechanism is quite a bit larger than the typical door latch. [Marchello](http://villedoors.com/door-hardware/marchello-modern-door-handle)  and  [Rome](http://villedoors.com/door-hardware/rome-modern-door-handle)

A second option would be to buy a European latch and fit it to the door. [Link](https://www.carlisleglass.co.uk/Products/001f0008003b0119)
The Backset is slightly different (57mm = 2 1/4" versus a typical US backset of 2 3/8") but it should be close enough to work. Worse case is that you can cut a round piece of wood to use as a filler and then redrill the Doorknob hole to match the European backset.

However with both of these options, one thing I noticed is that they will still make a click when the Door magnet pulls on the bolt as you can quite clearly hear in the following YouTube video.  [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTtKDQjj2oo)

Finally, the last and imho the best option for a quiet door handle is to install a 'Force Closer'. It basically replaces the Door knobs bolt and striker plate with a set of Magnets to keep the door closed.
[You Tube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iF4ykcjLg4) / [Website](https://forcecloser.net/product/force-closer-wood/)

Or you could just remove your Door knobs bolt and replace your existing latch with a Magnetic one and that would give you your quietly closing door (albeit one that you could not lock)  [Magnetic Door Catch](https://www.ebay.com/itm/6xStrong-Magnet-Attraction-Metal-Door-Catch-Latch-Cabinet-Cupboard-Glass-Suction/223772100324)

But at only around $10 or so, the Force Closer sounds like what your looking for.

Comment: I am going to give the force closer a try. The sit doesn't have a lot of info and measurements, etc. but worth trying. If not on my kid's doors, will be good to replace ball catches on the top of some double door closets.

Answer (score 1):

When closing the door -- turn the knob to retract the latch tongue, pull the door quietly shut and hold it there, then turn the knob back to quietly let the latch tongue into the strike plate.

With a little practice you can do this absolutely silently.

When your children are older they will learn to do this when they want to sneak out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cheap idea you can try now.

1. Turn handle so metal part is withdrawn completely into door.
2. Put a quarter over it.
3. Tape quarter into place with duct tape.  The quarter is because with just duct tape the metal protrusion piece will cut thru the tape pretty quick.

Now the door does not latch. You no longer use the latch. You can push it open and close it quietly.  You can glue some little bumpers where the door hits the jamb if you want.

It is easy to undo when your kids get older and want a door that can latch.

As you might have guessed it is a trick invented to prevent a door that automatically locks from locking.

Answer (score 0):

You might try grease instead of oil if looking for quiet (petroleum jelly is a relatively "clean" or "clear" grease that's found in most houses) and perhaps pack the strike plate hole with a hard grade of felt - either a bit to quiet operation while still latching, or completely to not latch.